# one project,many tomcat occurred session replaceed

Tags: java, tomcat, web, redis

```
1) one spring web project：DemoWeb.war
2) two tomcat (port: 8080/8081)
3) spring-session-redis(Using spring-session-redis to realize distributed session.)
```

deployed:

setp1:
useing this url http://ip:8080/demo/ login successful;

setp2:access menu url http://ip:8080/demo/menu successful;

setp3: open new tab in browser, and input http://ip:**8081**/demo/menu (port is difference), enter；

I don't login the **8081** server,
 why the http://ip:8081/demo/menu can access successful??

Answer (score 2):

If you store data in `HTTP Session`, it is stored in `Cookie` with the session Id. But if you are using `Redis`, data is stored in `Redis store` and not on tomcat with only the session ID passed to cookie in this scenario. Since the session ID is available to both the tomcats in browser and are pointing towards same Redis session, you find yourself logged in even if you change the port.

Comment: that's it!
even i setting difference database for the two web，web(8080)'s user table hava testUser1(not hava testUser2);  
and, web(8081)'s user table hava testUser2(not hava testUser1);  
the problem is also!!

Comment: Is there not hava any way？？

Comment: In a general scenario, both the servers must use same or mirrored datasource if same applications are running over them. To reduce the sync issues like the one you're facing. But if you want to have separate datasources for both apps, then you'll have to validate the data on backend also once you receive it on your controller.

Comment: If the user is difference，in my controller i can check；but if the user is same to both the tomcats （small probability），maybe also occurred some problem？ Other way， can i setting difference session id in some way？

Comment: Instead of setting a different session id, you may try adding a server specific environment variable and match them first.

Comment: thx，the last way i install tow different environment for the war。